# Funções do PYAUTOGUI não funcionando

Tags: python, python-3.x, automatização, pyautogui

Estou automatizando a instalação de um software utilizando python com pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import pyperclip

for window in pyautogui.getWindows():
    pyautogui.getWindow(window).minimize()

##Abre local do .exe
pyautogui.hotkey("win","r")
pyautogui.press("\\")
pyautogui.press("\\")
pyperclip.copy("ts1/publico/Meus Documentos/Equipes Qualidade/Automação/Aplicativos/Folha/Sefip 8.4")
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl","v")
pyautogui.press("enter")

##Encontra .exe e da double click nele
executavel = None
while executavel is None:
    executavel = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("executavel.png", grayscale=False)
executalvelX, executavelY = pyautogui.center(executavel)
pyautogui.click(executalvelX, executavelY, clicks=2)

##O instalador abre, aqui ele deveria encontrar o botão 'sim' e clicar nele.
##O Script encontra a posição do botao, porém não clica, não pressiona teclas, não move o mouse.
botaoSim = None
while botaoSim is None:
    botaoSim = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("botaosim.png", grayscale=False)
botaoSimX, botaoSimY = pyautogui.center(botaoSim)
pyautogui.click(botaoSimX, botaoSimY)

for _ in range(4):
    next1 = None
    while next1 is None:
        next1 = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("next.png", grayscale=False)
    next1X, next1Y = pyautogui.center(next1)
    pyautogui.click(next1X, next1Y)
```

Porém, em certa etapa do processo, algumas funções como clicar, mover o mouse, pressionar uma tecla não funcionam.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se estou fazendo algo de errado, ou se é pelo fato de ser uma instalação de um sistema.

Comment: O *script* continua rodando? Aparece algum erro?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O script permanece rodando, sem erros, ele encontra a posição do "sim" e segue adiante, passa pelo for (que vai clicando em next - também acontece a mesma coisa, encontra as posições mas passa reto pelo click)

Comment: O programa não terá perdido o foco?

Comment: Já testei essa possibilidade, porém não obtive sucesso, exceto se fiz errado...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Olá, Nathan! Desculpa responder um pouco tarde, mas passei por um problema semelhante agora.

A solução foi simplesmente abrir o aplicativo que eu queria clicar como **Administrador** e, magicamente, o mouse voltou a clicar na tela do aplicativo.

Espero que ajude!

Answer (score -1):

Se você instalar o OpenCV, você pode usar o recurso confidence.
Às vezes há pequenos ajustes e modificações nos pixeis de uma imagem e diminuir o nível de precisão na busca pode aumentar as chances de encontrar a imagem que quer.

x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('printscreen.png', confidence=0.8)
pyautogui.click(x, y)

Answer (score -2):

```
executavel = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("executavel.png",grayscale=True, confidence=0.9)
```

## Observação:

grayscale(True) = deixa a imagem em tons de cinza, melhora muito o reconhecimento
confidence(mínimo 0.1 máximo 1.0) = diz a fidelidade da imagem, mais próximo do real, varia entre 77 e 95 para melhores resultados, é uma precisão, quanto mais alto o valor, mais exato a imagem tem que ser. obs: usar acima de 0.9 da muito errado.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode resolver esse problema assim:

Gere um executável(.exe) do seu arquivo .py

Vá em propriedades do arquivo

Aperte em **Compatibilidade**

E marque a caixa **"Executar este programa como administrador"**

Answer (score -2):

Ao invés de importar o pyautogui como (import pyaotogui), faça com (from pyautogui import *)
Assim vc não precisa colocar pyautogui em cada linha. E no press você pode usar assim:

```
press("//", presses=2, interval=0.01) # Vai fazer o mesmo que as 2 linhas de comando press que usou no seu código
```

Comment: Por favor, explique na sua resposta como isso ajuda com a resolução do problema do post original (preferível citações e/ou documentação).

Answer (score -3):

Talvez não seja muito o contexto do problema ai, mas percebi que dependendo do programa e necessario trocar o metodo de pressionamento caso for comando de teclas, e sempre deixa o programa rodando em janela ao inves de tela cheia

```
pyautogui.keyDown("w")
pyautogui.keyUp("w")
```